# How exactly does completeness imply compactness?

Tags: first-order-logic, proof-theory

The general argument goes like so: suppose $\Sigma$ is finitely satisfiable, but not satisfiable. Therefore, $\Sigma$ is inconsistent, so $\Sigma \vdash \bot$. Then, by completeness, there exists a derivation from $\Sigma$ of $\bot$ and, since every proof is finite, there exists a derivation of $\bot$ from a finite subset. Done.

However, I've been thinking about the fact that I've never actually seen the completeness theorem proven for an infinite set $\Sigma$. If we try to prove it in sequent calculus, for example, we have to put $\Sigma$ into a sequent; we'd encode that as $\Sigma \implies \bot$ --- but that's not a sequent, as the antecedent is infinite. How is this resolved?

Comment: There is no barrier to making sense of derivation from an infinite set. If you're using a finite sequent calculus, then $\varphi$ being derivable from $\Sigma$ means there is a finite $\Sigma_0\subseteq \Sigma$ such that $\Sigma_0\implies \varphi$ is derivable. And you do need to address infinite sets in the proof of completeness if you want to use completeness to prove compactness.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Why don't we need to address them? When constructing a reduction tree in sequent calculus, we start with a sequent $S$ — a sequent is defined to have a *finite* antecedent and succedent — and we prove that it is either invalid or provable. Nothing is said of infinite sets.

Comment: I said you *do* need to address them. (Do you have an example of a proof of the completeness theorem that doesn't?) And I said how to make sense of a derivation from an infinite set in that case.

Comment: I was thinking of the proof of completeness from Takeuti's Proof Theory. Do you know of a proof which addresses this issue? To be fair, Takeuti never develops model theory, nor does he prove compactness. But clearly his completeness theorem is somewhat weaker than the general form, then.

Comment: Many general logic books, e.g. Enderton.

Comment: True, although Enderton works in natural deduction and a hilbertian system, not sequent calculus. The proof he gives works in seemingly any proof system pretty much the same, but I was hoping there was a way to adapt the reduction tree proof so that it worked for infinite sets. Is that possible?

Comment: Not familiar enough with that proof to say for sure, but would guess so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed some care needed here.

Consider second-order logic with full semantics, $\mathsf{SOL}$. Let $\vdash_0$ be the "finitary entailment relation" for $\mathsf{SOL}$: given a (possibly infinite) set of $\mathsf{SOL}$-sentences $\Gamma$ and a single $\mathsf{SOL}$-sentence $\varphi$ (for simplicity I'm only allowing single-sentence consequents), we set $\Gamma\vdash_0\varphi$ iff some finite $\Gamma_0\subseteq\Gamma$ has $\Gamma_0\models_\mathsf{SOL}\varphi$.

Trivially $\vdash_0$ is complete for finite sequents: if $\Gamma$ is finite then $\Gamma\vdash_0\varphi$ iff $\Gamma\models_\mathsf{SOL}\varphi$. However, we also know that $\models_\mathsf{SOL}$ is not compact, whereas $\vdash_0$ by definition is compact, so $\vdash_0$ is not complete on infinite sequents.

So what? Well, this shows that there is in general a gap between completeness for finitary sequents and full completeness in general logics. In the particular case of first-order logic each result is true, but there are settings where one result holds and the other doesn't. So in fact your original concern **was justified**: if we state the completeness theorem in its weak form, we do not trivially get the stronger form, let alone compactness.

Fortunately, this is easily addressed by looking at the **proof**. Even if we don't want to modify our definition of sequents to accommodate infinite antecedents, we're still fine: supposing $\Gamma$ is a possibly-infinite set of $\mathsf{FOL}$-sentences no finite subset $\Gamma_0$ of which has $\Gamma_0\vdash\varphi$ being a valid sequent, we build via the usual Henkinization argument a model of $\Gamma\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$. So the only way we get in trouble is if we phrase the conclusion of this argument too blithely and treat it as a blackbox.

Comment: The idea I came up with to fix this in the meantime was this: prove compactness independently, then apply it to an infinite set of antecedents and reduce to the weaker form of completeness. This is equivalent to your last paragraph, right? But it is good to know that it is possible to modify the proof system to include infinite antecedents.